# Lookbehind does not work as expected

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to understand the lookbehind.
This example I am trying doesn't work as I expected. I wanted to try to form a regex that would match `John` but not `John.`
The following:

```
$ perl -e '  
my $var = "John.";  
if( $var =~ m/J*/) {  
print "Matches!\n";  
}  
'  
Matches!
```

matches up to and including `.` of course. The problem is the following:

```
$ perl -e '  
my $var = "John.";  
if( $var =~ m/J*(?<![.])/) {  
print "Matches!\n";  
}  
'  
Matches!
```

For the latter I expected that the regex would match `John.` **consuming  >.< (the period)**
Then at the next position it would look behind and realize that it consumed a period (.) and would reject the match.
Is my understanding wrong? What am I messing up here?

**Update**:
Same result also for `my $var = "John. ";`

**Update 2**:
My question is not about how to match only `John` and not `John.`
But to understand how lookbehind works and if it is not supposed to work in this case why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` is a quantification operator, not a placeholder. So `A*` means zero or more `A` characters. Without any further context, this always matches, e.g. `"foo" =~ /J*/` is true.

What you intended to write was `/J.*/` which does what you've actually described.

Now let's look what happens when we do `"John." =~ /(J.*(?<![.]))/`:

- The regex engine sees `J`, which matches.
- The next pattern is `.*`, which matches `ohn.`.
- Next the assertion `(?<![.])` is tested, which fails.
- The regex engine therefore *backtracks*.
- We try `.*` again, but this time only match `ohn`.
- Next the assertion `(?<![.])` is tested, which suceeds.

In the above regex, I enclosed the pattern in a capture group, which we can now read out:

```
$ perl -E'"John." =~ /(J.*(?<![.]))/ and say "<$1>" or say "No match"'
<John>
```

It is often more efficient to use a character class instead of assertions and `.*` quantifications, so that we can avoid backtracking:

```
/J[^.]*/
```

However, this is not strictly equivalent to the above regexes.

Comment: @Jim: By the way, `/(J.*(?<![.]))/` matches a string starting with J and not ending with `.`, while `/J[^.]*/` matches a string starting with J and doesn't contain `.` character.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't say that backtracking is avoided, but rather that it's reduced. I would say that backtracking is avoided when using possessive quantifiers and atomic groups.

Comment: @nhahtdh:But will it backtrack to consume `John`?

Answer (score 0):

This regexp:

```
/John(?![.])/
```

will match `John` but not `John`. It uses a negative look-*ahead* assertion (rather than look-*behind*).

If you want to match full names other than 'John', you'll need to be a bit more specific about what you do and don't want to allow in the match, as putting `J*` will match zero or more `J`'s.

**Edit:** Obviously I misread the `*` per @amon's post. Look-ahead vs. look-behind still applies.

Comment: But my question is about understanding lookbehind. Not solve the problem of not matching `John.`

Comment: Look-behind looks BEFORE the current match. Not AFTER it.

Comment: edited. I misread your `J*` as `J.*`. @amon's post is correct.